# How do i add a JLabel in a JTable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

So i want to add a empty JLabel with a Background color to my JTable.
It's for a piechart and i want to add this so the legend matches.

code:

```
for (String result : queryResult) {

            JLabel label = new JLabel("Hallo: "+rowCount);
            label.setBackground(colors[rowCount]);
            label.setOpaque(true);

            String queryResultString = "";
            queryResultString = result.toString();
            String[] lineArray = queryResultString.split("////");

            String[] pieData = new String[3];

            pieData[0] = lineArray[0];
            pieData[1] = lineArray[rangId - 1];

            int value = Integer.parseInt(pieData[1]);
            double percentage = value / total * 100;

            pieData[2] = "" + percentage + "%";

            pieModel.addRow(new Object[] {label, pieData[0], pieData[1], pieData[2]});

            rowCount++;
        }

        pieTable.setDefaultRenderer(String.class, new DefaultTableCellRenderer() {

            @Override
            public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column){

                if(value instanceof JLabel){
                    //This time return only the JLabel without icon
                    return (JLabel)value;
                }else{
                    return super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
                }
            }
        });
```

What am i doing wrong? :o

When i look at the results in the first column of the table it says:

javax.swing.JLabel[,0,0,0......
can't see the rest but it definetly is not working as it should! :(

Answer (score 5):

> So i want to add a empty JLabel with a Background color to my JTable. It's for a piechart and i want to add this so the legend matches.

you can't do that [Renderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender) by default returs `Component`, `JComponent` or `JLabel`

Answer (score 3):

Every cell in JTable is already a JLabel. You need to customize getTableCellRendererComponent to return super.getTableCellRendererComponent with proper background color set to achieve the effect you are aiming for.

Answer (score 2):

`DefaultTableCellRenderer` inherit from `JLabel` (that inherit from `JComponent`). So you can change the JLabel properties within `getTableCellRendererComponent`.

[For example](http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=703279) :

```
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("images/moon.gif"));// prepared before

public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
                                             boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, 
                                             int row, int column) {     
    setText((String)value);
    setIcon(icon);
    return this;
}
```

`setText` come from the super JLabel class and `setIcon` from the super JComponent class.

Almost all `DefaultTableCellRenderer` methods override method from these classes.